# How would you recommended to filter comments which contains offensive words defined in a huge list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, search, filtering

To be short:

JAVA/Hibernate/AJAX/SpringMVC

I would like that every comment which is posted by a user should be read on the server side **before storing it into the database** and **reject the comment if it contains an offensive text**.

The offensive text list is quite huge (maybe thousands). look at this example list: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/lists/most-vulgar-words/

I guess that iterating this list and execute a function like the following is not so fast. Is there any other way to do this filter more faster? 
Do you think search over thousandths of items will have a big impact over resources CPU/RAM? Any suggestion is welcomed!

```
for(String offensiveText : offensiveTextList ){     
    if(commentText.contains(offensiveText )){
         //reject comment
    }
}
```

Update:
The offensive item list can contain items composed by a few words inside it (like a 3 words text, and **can** contain stop words). 
It can contain even non alphabet characters like *&^%.

If the comment contains the respective offensive item (exactly **same** letters) then it is considered rejected

Comment: My first step would be to test if is fast or not. Use some kind of  online/electronic dictionary or word-list to compile a list of words to search for, and then run the above code with it over some test text. That way you don't need to 'guess' that it's not so fast. You can re-use your test once you have a different algorithm

Comment: Even in English some words have different meanings depending on the context. A male chicken for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably need to use some natural language processing library for this. If you are going to compare every *M* word from a comment with *N* offensive words from a list, then your algorithm complexity is going to be `O(MN) = O(N^2)`, which is quite high.

Take a look at the [Lucene stack](https://lucene.apache.org/), you may find some really good ideas, for example how to tokenize a comment and reduce the input by removing meaningless words.

Also take a look at the thesis: ["Distinguishing Between Factual Information and Insulting or Abusive Messages bearing Words or Phrases in News Articles"](http://dspace.bracu.ac.bd/bitstream/handle/10361/96/Distinguishing%20between%20factual%20information%20and%20insulting%20or%20abusive.pdf?sequence=1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better solution would be to put the words from the text in a Set, and then do a check on the entire set to see if the intersection had any elements.

You could also do a check for the most common english words and remove them(I, and, the etc.)

Comment: A small update: the offensive item list can contain items composed by  a few words inside it (like a 3 words, and can contain stop words). It can contain even non alphabet characters like *&^%.  If the comment contains the respective offensive item (exactly same letters) then it is rejected

Answer (score 0):

You prepare a String with unique offensive words appending one after one.

then check `offensivewordsString.contains(commentedText).`

In commentedText will contains only main words

Answer (score 0):

Is the word list based on language as well? Maybe it would be worth scanning only the language of the poster first, allowing them through if it is clean and then have scheduled processes to search for other offensive foreign language words after posting when the server is not busy.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the offensiveWordList into some sort of memory cache like a HashSet, then split your comment text into words and then check each word for existence in the HashSet.

A hashset lookup would use fewer resources than iterating over the whole offensive list each time.

I'm assuming your offensive words are relatively static - pay attention to threading if the list is updated online.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all of your offensive words into Set;

   `Set<String> offensiveWords = new HashSet<String>();`
2. Remove all ""the","a","by" "on", etc.. words from comment.
3. Split your comment into `String[] word` by space character.
4. Check if `Set<String> offenciveWords` contains words from `String[] word`

It will give you much faster performance.

Comment: Sorry. cannot split into words the offensive items. Also the offensiveText can contain stop words.

Comment: 1) In your question you said that you have offensive word List. Why can't it be Offensive words Set? 2. What are stop Words? why can't you split the comment into separate words?