# High performance badwords filter (PHP/MySQL/JS) with large list

Tags: php, forms, performance, validation, filter

I'm currently working on a web form allowing users to post a message to be processed in some kind of media. As we have to validate the input and parse it against a given badwords list, I drove into many options to choose from. But as the list arrived and holds about 15,000 words to match against I'm wondering how to process these the most efficient way. Maybe you can help me out!

Basically this can be a backend filter, but an additional frontend approval in javascript would be appreciated (in case, maybe an async ajax request to the backend?). The form will be used in a high traffic environment and any asynchronous checkups after submission can be left out as we need instant feedback to the users and don't want to only censor their input.

We use PHP 5.4.0, have an MySQL 5.5 InnoDB attached and do prefer not to use any third party projects as they mostly come with some kind of overload IMHO.

Comment: Some hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948189/how-would-you-recommended-to-filter-comments-which-contains-offensive-words-defi

Comment: Thanks Marki555, this heads to the right direction!

Comment: Consider whether this is what you actually want, and how it will affect the user experience. Over zealous censoring can be an enormous pain ("Why doesn't it let me say my name is Dick and I live in Scunthorpe?"), and people will f1nd w@y5 2 w()rk  @ r 0 |_| n d  !t anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948189/how-would-you-recommended-to-filter-comments-which-contains-offensive-words-defi) has some suggestions on what software to use.

But in fact 15000 isn't that much - with avg of 5 chars per word it is under 100 kB of data. If the requirement is not to use any other software, then you could use some simple approach to have less comparisons.

First divide your badwords dictionary into lists of same word lengths (so instead of comparing every word with all possible badwords, you will compare it against the ones which have the same length).

Then you have 2 possibilities and you have to benchmark which one is faster:

- For each word from the user post, compute its length and compare against all badwords of the same length.
- Or try to get all words into an array and remove duplicates - and only after that check against the badwords

Using this, you will eliminate the number of comparations to the minimum, although you will still need to do a lot of them.

NOTE: This approach works for badwords which are plain words. If your badwords dictionary contain also phrases (more words with spaces between them), you have either to use specialized software or do the comparison in the opposite way (for each badword phrase, try to find it in the whole submitted post).

Another question is if you really need to check for all 15000 badwords and if their potentional frequency in your posts is worth the computation effort. Also I guess that for such high traffic site you already have some sort of moderation which catch all posts that are not caught by the system itself (and maybe spam posts will be more common than those with badwords).

Comment: Thanks, great idea to simply split the wordlist up. I'll try this and compare a bit. Think a str_pos against a list in memory will do the trick. Moderation is out, due to the fact, that the free textfield value will be rendered on the fly to a shareable video - and this async validation process is not part of the concept! :-P

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous HTTP request to a php script makes most sense to me, actually the only thing that makes sense. No submiting or refreshing needed.

Comment: The question was more on about how to implement fast word searching, not how to call/submit it.

Comment: well he wanted instant feedback

Comment: Just want to give instant feedback to the users, when entering "bad" text. But this is more a performance/optimization question!

Comment: `well he wanted instant feedback` - I took that to be a justification for the poor quality of your answer, but that's not what you meant, is it?

Comment: I seem to have completely misunderstood the question. My bvad